# pyfits and mayvi installed package in astroconda but not visible by spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, spyder, pyfits

I have installed astroconda. After activating astroconda by command `source activate astroconda` I typed `spyder`. Then in Spyder I imported some package `import pyfits` and `from mayavi import mlab`
I see this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named pyfits

I checked with `conda list` and pyfits 3.3  is in installed package list. How tell Spyder to use this package?

Answer (score 1):

Spyder it is not included by default in [astroconda](https://astroconda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package_manifest.html). So, when you load it, it uses the version in the Ananconda environment.

To solve this, you only have to install it in astroconda:

```
source activate astroconda
conda install spyder
```